# Android JNI: Getting the parent class

Tags: android, reflection, android-ndk, java-native-interface, native-code

I am trying to pass whichever Activity is active to some C++ code written with NDK.

If for example I pass a reference to a MainActivity object, (or perhaps SettingsActivity), how can I call a method such as getName() which is in the Object class?

If I declare my own Java method "giveMeName()" to return getClass.getName(), then giveMeName() works fine but of course its limited to the class in which I declared it. How can I call Object::getName() from within the C++ code - without modifying the Java code to pass an Object reference.

EDIT:

I thought I had it working - I saw the class name being returned at some point but now its not. I still get null returned when trying to get getName():

```
    // PDS: Get the class - should be some sort of Activity subclass..
    jclass clsActivity = pEnv->GetObjectClass( pObj2 );

    if( JNIException( pEnv ) )
      return;

    LogDebugf( "PDS> naNewActivity::clsActivity: %08lx\n", (long) clsActivity );

    if( ! clsActivity )
      return;

    jmethodID mid_getClass = pEnv->GetMethodID( clsActivity, "getClass", "()Ljava/lang/Class;");

    LogDebugf( "PDS> naNewActivity::getClass methodID: %08lx\n", (long) mid_getClass );

    if( JNIException( pEnv ) )
      return;

    // PDS: Call getClass() method on Activity object ( actually Object::getClass() )
    jclass c = (jclass) pEnv->CallObjectMethod( pObj2, mid_getClass );

    LogDebugf( "PDS> naNewActivity::getClass() returns: %08lx\n", (long) c );

    if( JNIException( pEnv ) )
      return;

    // PDS: If we get a Class object, call Class::getName()
    jmethodID mid_getName = pEnv->GetMethodID( c, "getName", "()Ljava/lang/String;");

    LogDebugf( "PDS> naNewActivity::getName methodID: %08lx\n", (long) mid_getName );

*** I AM GETTING null being returned for mid_getName

    if( JNIException( pEnv ) )
      return;

    // PDS: Call method on Activity object ( Object::getName() )
    jobject   n = pEnv->CallObjectMethod( pObj2, mid_getName );

    if( JNIException( pEnv ) )
      return;

    jstring   sName = (jstring) n;

    char *pszData = (char*) pEnv->GetStringUTFChars( sName, JNI_FALSE );

    LogDebugf( "PDS> naNewActivity, class name[%s]\n", pszData );
    pEnv->ReleaseStringUTFChars( sName, pszData );
```

FIXED CODE: I figured out with Seva's help below:

```
// PDS: Get the class - should be some sort of Activity subclass..
jclass clsActivity = pEnv->GetObjectClass( pObj2 );

if( JNIException( pEnv ) )
  return;

LogDebugf( "PDS> naNewActivity::clsActivity: %08lx\n", (long) clsActivity );

if( ! clsActivity )
  return;

jmethodID mid_getClass = pEnv->GetMethodID( clsActivity, "getClass", "()Ljava/lang/Class;");

LogDebugf( "PDS> naNewActivity::getClass() methodID: %08lx\n", (long) mid_getClass );

if( JNIException( pEnv ) )
  return;

// PDS: Call getClass() method on Activity object.. ( actually Object::getClass() )
jclass c = (jclass) pEnv->CallObjectMethod( pObj2, mid_getClass );

LogDebugf( "PDS> naNewActivity::getClass() returns: %08lx\n", (long) c );

if( JNIException( pEnv ) )
  return;

jclass clsClass   = pEnv->GetObjectClass( c );

LogDebugf( "PDS> naNewActivity::clsClass: %08lx\n", (long) clsClass );

if( JNIException( pEnv ) )
  return;

// PDS: If we get a Class object, call Class::getName()
jmethodID mid_getName = pEnv->GetMethodID( clsClass, "getName", "()Ljava/lang/String;");

LogDebugf( "PDS> naNewActivity::getName() methodID: %08lx\n", (long) mid_getName );

if( JNIException( pEnv ) )
  return;

// PDS: Can't call method on Activity object - need to call it on its Class (object) ( Class::getName() )
jobject   n = pEnv->CallObjectMethod( c, mid_getName );

if( JNIException( pEnv ) )
  return;

jstring   sName = (jstring) n;

char *pszData = (char*) pEnv->GetStringUTFChars( sName, JNI_FALSE );

LogDebugf( "PDS> naNewActivity, class name[%s]\n", pszData );
pEnv->ReleaseStringUTFChars( sName, pszData );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You use the `java.lang.Object` class to look up the method ID, then you use the object pointer of the derived class instance to call the method. JNI permits that. First, you'd have to find the class ID of `java.lang.Object` by its name.

Comment: @Seva Alekseyev: Thanks. I've tried "jclass clsObject = pEnv->FindClass( "java/lang/Object" );" but that returns null. Is there something wrong with my syntax?

Comment: @Seva Alekseyev: Please have a look at the updated code in the question. I'm sure the method ID for getName() was returning (it did print my class name earlier) but I don't know what I've done to break it since.

Comment: I don't think the object pointer of a `Class` object can be used as a jclass. Retrieve the class object for `Class` by calling `pEnv->GetObjectClass(c)` and then `GetMethodID()` for that one.

Comment: @Seva Alekseyev: Yeah, I'm actually trying to call GetMethodId() on c which is the object and I should be calling GetMethodId() on the class itself. That looks like the problem.. lets see..

Comment: @Seva Alekseyev: Thanks for your help. Figured it out. I've posted the solution into the question. The confusion was about getting the Class of the Class object returned. :-) I gotta be getting better a this now!

Comment: You don't need the ID of `java.lang.Object` *at all.*

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to modify the code. If the method is accessible at all, the code to call it is identical to the code you would use if the method was declared in the derived class.

Comment: I'm afraid that doesn't work. The getName() method cannot be found on the (Main)Activity class.

Comment: Aha! I have just found that an Object doesn't have a getName() method - it only has getClass().. which returns a Class. Class has the getName() method, so that would make sense with what you said. I should be able to call getClass() on my SettingsActivity for example, and then call getName() on the Class returned. If that works I'll accept your answer.. with my comments ;-)